# ¿Cómo pasar un query a un Stored Procedure?

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedure

Tengo un Stored Procedure el cual deseo completar la consulta enviandole ciertas condiciones en el `Where` Los cuales los mandaré por **`prepareCall`**

**Stored Procedure**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `exampleFilter`(_QUERY VARCHAR(10000))
BEGIN
SELECT * FROM department WHERE _QUERY;
END
```

**LLamada del Stored Procedure y envío del Query**

```
call exampleFilter("Department_Name LIKE CONCAT('S','%')")
```

El motivo de esto es que no quiero formar consultas dentro de mi código en la aplicación, pero me encuentro en el problema que tengo que armar una consulta para filtrar con varios datos y pensé que pudiera armar el query y pasarlo al Stored Procedure.

Comment: @A.Cedano alguna idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes utilizar `PREPARE` y `EXECUTE`.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE exampleFilter(_QUERY VARCHAR(10000))
  BEGIN

      set @body = CONCAT('SELECT * FROM deparment WHERE ', _QUERY, ';');

      PREPARE stmnt FROM @body;
      EXECUTE stmnt;

  END
```

**Nota**: no olvides el espacio entre el `WHERE` y la consulta.

Luego podrás llamar con:

```
call exampleFilter("Department_Name LIKE CONCAT('S','%')");
```

Comment: Probare el código para dar la pregunta como cerrada

Comment: Probare el código para dar la pregunta como cerrada

Answer (score -1):

Tambien podrias armar con sql dinamico las consultas dentro del procedure, enviarle solo los parametros y olvidarte de crear las consultas en la aplicacion, usando un parametro que indique el tipo de consulta por medio de ifs:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `tuprocedure`(in TipoConsulta varchar(30),in campo1 varchar(30),
in dato1 varchar(30),in campo2 varchar(30),in dato2 varchar(30))
BEGIN

/* si tipoconsulta es 1 */
if tipoconsulta = '1'
SET @s = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM tabla where ",campo1," = ",dato1," and ",campo2," = ",dato2,"");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;   
end if;

/* si tipoconsulta es 2 */
if tipoconsulta = '2'
SET @s = CONCAT("SELECT * FROM tabla where ",campo1," = ",dato1," and ",campo2," = ",dato2,"");
    PREPARE stmt FROM @s;
    EXECUTE stmt;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;   
end if;

END
```

A mí esto me resulta mas cómodo a la hora de hacer mantenimiento/actualizaciones en programas que empiezan a crecer y crecer, ya que no tengo que modificar  todas las consultas en archivos de código, directamente hago las modificaciones o añadir funcionalidades en el procedure.

un saludo!

Comment: El problema que le veo, es a la hora de que ella más se de dos filtros, sería una cantidad muy grande de parámetros. También busco crear un solo Stored Procedure para todas las consultas de filtros y solo modificar Parámetros con la menor cantidad